# Make Azure calls only through proxy

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

I'm trying to make my Azure instance use a proxy server for all the calls he makes.
Im creating an azure instance:
`Azure azure = Azure.configure().withProxy(createProxy(hasProxy)).authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId)`

My create proxy method:

```
    private static Proxy createProxy(String hostPort) throws ServiceWareException {
        String[] arr = hostPort.split(":");
        String host = arr[0];
        String port = arr[1];
        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(host, Integer.parseInt(port));
        return new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
    }
```

After doing this I can see in my proxy server call to `login.microsoftonline.com:443.`
The problem is this is the only time Azure making calls through my proxy.

Im listing  VMs,networkWatchers, loadbalances and etc...
everything with `azure` variable I've created before.

EDIT:
to be more precise, I doesn't make sense to me that azure making only one request through my proxy server while I'm making the actions above, so I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: thanks for telling me that my issue isn't that clear, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId,
                tenant,
                clientSecret,
                AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        credentials.withProxy(createProxy());

        Azure azure = Azure.configure()
                .withProxy(createProxy())
                .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS)
                .authenticate(credentials)
                .withSubscription(subId);

private static Proxy createProxy() {

        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("", Integer.parseInt(""));
        return new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);

    }
```

Comment: Hi Jim Xu, can you please describe what's the benefits of writing the code this way?

Comment: @OmriMalka please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/13720#issuecomment-682133066